# Call to a member function prepare() on null

Tags: laravel, mongodb

Estoy intentando programar un crud en laravel con mongodb como base. Puedo realizar la registración y login, pero cuando quiero dar de alta un ítem determinado, me da error.

El código es:

```
    public function guardaritem(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
        'name' => 'required',
        'tipo' => 'required',
        'cantidad' => 'required',
        ]);
        $data=$request->all();
        Item::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'tipo' => $data['tipo'],
        'cantidad' => $data['cantidad'],
        ]);

        return redirect('/Item')->with('message','El Producto se guardo correctamente');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public function guardaritem(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
    'name' => 'required',
    'tipo' => 'required',
    'cantidad' => 'required',
    ]);
    $data=$request->all();
    Item::create([
    'name' => $data['name'],
    'tipo' => $data['tipo'],
    'cantidad' => $data['cantidad'],
    ]);
```

> la coma ',' al final de $data['cantidad'], php esta esperando otro atributo por eso te salta el error